# Spark Sql 1.3.0 + parquet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

USING SPARK-SQL:
i've created a table without parquet in hdfs and everything is ok.
i've created the same table structure but with "store as parquet", also i've created the parquet files and upload to hdfs and "load inpath 'hdfs://servever/parquet_files'

but when i try to execute "select * from table_name";

i've this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://server:8020/user/hive/warehouse/table_name, expected: file:///
```

any tip??

Comment: Can you show your whole code please?

Comment: If you have solved this can you use the answer box provided ....

Comment: Actually, this is pretty specific to you. So, it might be worth just removing your answer and deleting the question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed including hadoop configuration files (core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml) in spark